# how to add write buffer into write defined in io.h

Tags: c++, buffer

I am using write( fd, buffer, count ) in io.h to write buffer into a file descriptor.

Now I found huge performance issue, because every time I call "write" it will perform a IO operation.

I want to add a buffer before actually writing content into file.

What is the best way to do this?

I searched and found this:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0240__File-Stream/filedescriptoroutbuffer.htm

Should I use this method and integrate into my code? Is that a good approach I should take?

But in it, I don't see how do define the buffer size.

Following is the final code:

```
class fdoutbuf : public std::streambuf {
    protected:
        enum { size = 4096 };
        int fd;    // file descriptor
        char buf_[size];
    public:
    // constructor
    fdoutbuf (int _fd) : fd(_fd) {
        setp(this->buf_, this->buf_ + size - 1);
    }
    protected:
    // write one character
    virtual int overflow (int c){
        if (c != EOF) {
            char z = c;
            *this->pptr() = z;
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return this->sync() == -1? EOF: c;
    }
    virtual int sync(){
         if (this->pbase() == this->pptr()) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count(this->pptr() - this->pbase());
        int rc = write(fd, this->buf_, count);
        this->setp(this->buf_, this->buf_ + size - 1);
        return count == rc? 0: -1;
    }
};


class fdostream : public std::ostream {
  protected:
    fdoutbuf buf;
  public:
    fdostream (int fd) : std::ostream(0), buf(fd) {
        rdbuf(&buf);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the buffering infrastructure isn't really rocket science but also isn't entirely trivial. Personally, I would just create a class derived from `std::streambuf` and either use the stream buffer abstraction or a stream (probably I would use the latter and accept the small performance impact introduced by most implementations). The work need to do this is fairly simple (this is for writing only):

```
struct fdbuf: std::streambuf {
    enum { size = 4096 };
    fdbuf(int fd): fd_(fd) { this->setp(this->buf_, this->buf_ + size - 1); }
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (!traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof())) {
            *this->pptr() = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return this->sync() == -1? traits_type::eof(): traits_type::not_eof(c);
    }
    int sync() {
        if (this->pbase() == this->pptr()) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count(this->pptr() - this->pbase());
        int rc = write(this->fd_, this->buf_, count);
        this->setp(this->buf_, this->buf_ + size - 1);
        return count == rc? 0: -1;
    }
    int  fd_;
    char buf_[size];
};
```

It seems it may be worth explaining what the stream buffer above actually does (given the lengthy discussion below). So, here is a breakdown:

- The code uses a fixed size buffer. This is just to reduce the size of the example: it can be easily extended to use a variable sized buffer which is allocated e.g. using a `std::vector<char>`: the size would become a default parameter.
- the function `setp()` sets up a buffer used by the stream buffer, consisting of three pointers:

  - `pbase()` is the start of the buffer, i.e. the first parameter to `setp()`
  - `epptr()` is the end of the buffer, i.e. the second parameter to `setp()`
  - `pptr()` is set to the same value as `pbase()` but is the pointer which is actually moved to indicate the position of the next character. If this is `epptr()` when a character is written `overflow()` is called.
- The virtual function `overflow()` is possibly given the character which caused the buffer to overflow. Unless it is called by user code with an argument of `eof()` this is the case when the standard library calls the function. To deal with this extra character, the buffer is given one element less there is available space: the character can be appended to the buffer before the buffer is actually written.
- The `traits_type` inherited from `std::streambuf` defines a number of functions to determine properties of characters. When checking the parameter passed to `overflow()` the function `eq_int_type()` is used which compares to objects of the stream's integer type for equality. It compares the argument to `overflow()` with the value indicating an invalid character which is obtained using `eof()`. All members of the traits type are `static` or `typedef`s, i.e. there is no need to use an object of this type. The use of the `traits_type` is important when using different template instantiations of `std::basic_streambuf`.
- Although the buffer is normally `pbase()` to `epptr()` with `pptr()` between these two ends, `pptr()` can be moved beyond `epptr()` using `pbump(n)`: this function just adds `n` to `pptr()`. This is used to put the currecnt character into the buffer right before calling `sync()` which just writes the content of the buffer and resets it.
- The return of `overflow()` is `eof()` if the function failed. On successful execution the function returns something different than `eof()` and conventionally the character passed as argument is used. As the argument may be `eof()` it isn't good enough to just return the argument, though: if it is `eof()` this value needs to be transformed into some other useful value which is what `not_eof()` does: it returns it arguments unless the argument is `eof()` in which case it returns some suitable other value.
- The virtual function `sync()` is responsible for flushing the buffer. In this case it is first checking that there is something to be done and, if so, writes the content of the buffer. There isn't really any trick in this function although I guess a proper one would be more careful if the `write()` fails, i.e. returns fewer characters than are characters in the buffer. This version just pretends that it is OK to loose characters which couldn't be written although it will indicate an error.
- The function still resets the buffer using the same approach of leaving one character space at the end of the buffer.
- Upon failure the function returns `-1`, on success it return `0`. No trick.

Comment: It is a little advanced for me. Can you take a look at this link: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0240__File-Stream/filedescriptoroutbuffer.htm. You both use streambuf, but implementation is different. Can I use the one in the link? But another question is the one is the link has no control for buf size.

Comment: Actually, the link is pointing to another version of the code of mine! ;) I had written it originally for Nico's book when I translated his German book. Except for errors (the code above isn't tested), this is roughly doing the same but without a  buffer and the version above also uses a few neat tricks. You can allocate a suitable buffer (of a `std::vector<char>` with appropriate size) in either version. Nico's book explains what is going on: maybe you should have a look there.

Comment: What a coincidence. Then can you tell me how to add buffer into the code in link? It looks more readable to me.

Comment: After more research, I changed the code in the link like this: fdoutbuf (int _fd, char_type* buffer, std::streamsize bufferLength) : fd(_fd) {
  setp(buffer, buffer + bufferLength);
    } I will allocate a buffer before init the fdoutbuf. Is that good? Or maybe I need to implement setbuf()?

Comment: There is no need to use `setbuf()`. However, note that you need to be prepared that `overflow()` adds a character (if its argument isn't equal to `traits_type::eof()`): this is why I'm using `size-1`. Also, note that you want to be able to flush the buffer which is what `sync()` does (Nico's version doesn't need this as it doesn't buffers). If you take these things into account I think you will find that you pretty much arrive at the code above...!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I have been learn it the whole day and it is really urgent for me to implement it. I would be really appreciated if you can extend the code in the link with buffer size setting. It doesn't need to be the same as code above(which include the buffer).

Comment: Your changed code sets up a buffer but doesn't use the buffer in `overflow()`! You need to use the buffer. Also, if you do buffering, you probably should get rid of `xsputn()`: this is really only needed to avoid `overflow()` being called for individual character. Also, the buffer isn't reset. In return, you definitely want `sync()`. What's wrong with using the code in my answer?

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Let me change my code. At the same time, Can you point out a place that explain the internal working mechanism?

Comment: Also I am not familiar with traits. Can you modify you code to get rid of it?

Comment: Well, descriptions can be found on the e.g. by searching for "Dietmar Kuehl" or "James Kanze" in comp.lang.c++ and comp.lang.c++.moderated. Otherwise, you can have a look at Nicolai Josuttis's book ("The C++ Standard Library") or Angelika Langer and Klaus Kreft's "IOStreams and Locales". With respect to the `traits_type`: you just want to use this as well!

Comment: The use of `traits_type` is pretty straight forward anyway: `eof()` just gets you the correct value use for the invalid character; `eq_int_type()` compares two objects of the stream's integer type for equality, i.e. `traits_type::eq_int_type(x, y)` is essentially `x == y`; the interesting one is `to_char_type()` which converts to `int` passed in as argument to a `char`. Mostly this is needed when the stream buffer is a template (the only tricky conversion is `char` to `int` and this isn't used).

Comment: Thanks traits looks very powerful. I will continue to learn it after resolving this problem. I have updated my post, can you take a look. By the way, what if it never overflow? and how to handle the buffer after hitting EOF? Basically the last couple chars. How to write it to file. Should the caller handle it?

Comment: You want to get rid of the `OsdWrite()` in `overflow()`: you already write the character in `sync()`. It would appear out of place prior to the buffer you writing (for testing this you might want to set the buffer size e.g. to `10` temporarily to see overflows happen). There is nothing "wrong" with `overflow()` it is just signalling that it is time to write the current content of the buffer and/or to make space in the buffer. What happens when the buffer never overflows? In this case it should be flushed which is what `sync()` is about: when an `std::ostream` is flushed `sync()` is called.

Comment: You might want to add a call to `sync()` to the destructor. Other than this, if the stream buffer is used by an `std::ostream` the stream buffer is flushed when the `std::ostream` is called. To deal with the last couple of characters it is probably worth to also call `sync()` from the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you writing in C++, you may try to use `STL` and `<fstream>` for output into files. It has already build in buffer and don't have such problems with speed.

Comment: But I need to use file descriptor. The infrastructure has been there